how to configure vscode workspace intellisense
I have a code base with a lot of different c source files in different folders. For projects we want to configure a project folder and reference different source folders from that project. I configured this using CMake and it al compiles fine. Also vscode shows me de code file I need for that project. But intellisense is not working.
CMake generates a compile_commands.json file for me, from which I understand I can use to configure intellisense. But how? I have c_cpp_properties.json file with the folling content:
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}

I have the following folder structure:

projects/my_app

.vscode

vscode.code-workspace
c_cpp_properties.json


build

compile_commands.json


source

app.c
app.h


CMakeLists.txt


components

component1

source

component1.c
component1.h




component2

source

component2.c
component2.h






my_lib

source

...


CMakeLists.txt



I also have some extra sources which are not visible in the vscode workspace. But are included in de CMakeLists.txt.
I cannot get intellisense to work.
I expected to use intellisense in vscode for my workspace.
